# Removing last child in list

Tags: jquery, list

I have a list which is used as a fly out menu from one of the sidebars of a site I am building.

I am trying to remove the last `<li>` item via javascript as the CMS behind the site builds this list on the fly, so I cannot remove it in the HTML per se.

I have run into an odd situation whereby the code I have works with IE, Safari and FireFox but not Chrome. In Chrome's case the code removes the last two items of the list.

Menu / list:

```
<div class="SideCategoryListFlyout">
   <ul class="sf-menu sf-vertical sf-js-enabled">
      <li>
         <a class="sf-with-ul" href="http://myurl/clearance/">
         Clearance
         <span class="sf-sub-indicator"> »</span>
         </a>
         <ul style="display: none; visibility: hidden;"> </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a class="sf-with-ul" href="http://myurl/Promotions/">
         Promotions
         <span class="sf-sub-indicator"> »</span>
         </a>
         <ul style="display: none; visibility: hidden;"> </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a class="sf-with-ul" href="http://myurl/Notebooks/">
         Notebooks
         <span class="sf-sub-indicator"> »</span>
         </a>
         <ul style="display: none; visibility: hidden;"> </ul>
      </li>
      <li>                                                          <-- REMOVE
         <a class="sf-with-ul" href="http://myurl/REMOVE/">         <-- REMOVE
         REMOVE                                                     <-- REMOVE  
         <span class="sf-sub-indicator"> »</span>                   <-- REMOVE
         </a>                                                       <-- REMOVE  
         <ul style="display: none; visibility: hidden;"> </ul>      <-- REMOVE
      </li>                                                         <-- REMOVE
   </ul>
</div>
```

My Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.SideCategoryListFlyout li:last-child').remove();
});
</script>
```

Comment: At first, why don't you not generate this last LI?

Comment: Looks like your `load` handler is running twice in Chrome. Do you have code somewhere that could trigger the `load` event a second time on Chrome browsers?

Comment: @roasted He said why he cant not generate the last LI.

Comment: @Jimmery But the CMS generate it from somewhere, no? But that's ok if OP find it easier to do it client side, i just hope is not trying to remove some copyright or something like that which would be not fair...

Comment: Works fine for me (Chrome 28). Can you try out the JSFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/a8sk5/ and see what that does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just hide it, using CSS rule should work in all case:

```
.SideCategoryListFlyout ul.sf-menu > li:last-child {
   display:none;
}
```

Comment: Hi @roasted, I like your suggestion best, but it does not work in my case. Could it be the menu is created by the CMS's javascript (Superfish's)? Thanks!

Comment: @user2469528 if you could provide an online link to check what's going on, it would be easier to help. Maybe the selector is not accurate or a CSS rule override it. For example, you could try to force it using `!important` statement

Comment: Hi @roasted, many thanks for your offer to look at the site! The link is https://itoutlet.com.au. I have implemented only your solution in CSS with !Important, but it still does not do the job. Thanks for the help offer!

Comment: @user2469528 you should use `.SideCategoryListFlyout` as selector. Sorry, i made a mistake.

Comment: Sorry @roasted, I cannot follow your suggestion, can you elaborate for me please. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Which LI do you want to hide, 'WD store'? If yes, add at end of CSS file e.g styles.css: `.SideCategoryListFlyout ul.sf-menu > li:last-child {
   display:none !important;
}`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps Chrome is loading the window twice. It is common to wait for the document to be ready, rather than for the window to load. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.SideCategoryListFlyout ul li:last').remove();
});
</script>
```

EDIT:

Ive checked this works, in both Chrome and FireFox, here: http://jsfiddle.net/n6fQ8/

Comment: Hi @Jimmery, thanks for the suggestion. When I try your code though, Chrome deletes the second last item, and the other browsers delete none... maybe insanity is setting in!! :-(

Comment: Could the <ul>..</ul> included in each <li> be the cause of this? It is BigCommerce generated code I cannot change any other way...

Comment: See my edit - I think the best approach here is to fire the remove() command when the document is ready, and from there its just a matter of finding the right selector to get at the last LI.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your CMS using Superfish's plug-in

hack like this..

```
$('.SideCategoryListFlyout').on('mouseenter.sfremove',function(){
        $('>ul > li', this).last().remove();
        $(this).off('mouseenter.sfremove');
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/2hFXx/2

Comment: Hi I2aelba, same result as Jimmery's suggestion. Chrome removes 2nd last item, FF, SF & IE do not remove any items?! Thanks

Comment: @user2469528 Okey, lets try to setInterval() for testing first ... demo : http://jsfiddle.net/Y5LYB/2/ , So if this work, That about your CMS gen html by using JS

Comment: Hi, your example is removing all entries one by one (I guess it is re-running and removing the last entry every time). I have tried the code above but without success.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
$('.SideCategoryListFlyout li').last().remove();
```

or if you wanna for few li you can use this one : `$('.SideCategoryListFlyout').children().slice(0, n).remove();`